# Cutomizing Button in Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I want to customize a button in Excel macro.Like giving a rounded shape to the button.Can anyone help me how to do this.I want to customize existing button.

[image]

Comment: Use a shape (assign a macro to it) instead of a button.

Comment: BigBen is correct.  It is very easy to customize a `TextBox`that you can insert from the *Insert* tab on the Ribbon.